# How can I merge roads layers that do not align perfectly?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, layers, merge, road, alignment

I have multiple roads layers for a given area and would like to merge them into one layer since they each have some unique roads the other layer does not show. However, the roads that these layers share in common ***do not align perfectly.*** Therefore, if I just merge the two layers, all of those roads will be shown twice in slightly different places. [image: Misaligned roads]

Is there any way to make some sort of tolerance where it won't duplicate roads displayed a few meters apart, for example? Or should I just merge them anyway and deal with a messier and somewhat more confusing layer when they're merged?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

Comment: as a quick & dirty option I would suggest to use the `buffer` tool on one of the feature classes (i.e. your red lines). use the buffered dataset to clip all the road parts of your second feature class (blue lines) that overlap. you might end up with a messy dataset too, but you could then use the `trim line` and `extend line` functions to clean it up. I'm sure there will be prettier solutions, but this might point you in the right direction.